# Hibernate Cast "arraylist" from List POJO to another POJO?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm try with hibernate and their POJO, cast to my POJO but have **classcastexception** How can fix?

```
private void open() throws Exception {
    //private ArrayList<Curso> listaCursos = new ArrayList<Curso>();
    try {
        sf = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        se = sf.openSession();
        Query query = se.createQuery("FROM Curso");

        System.out.println(listaCursos);
        List<Curso> lisst = new ArrayList<Curso>();
        for (Object c : query.list()) {
            listaCursos.add((Curso) c);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

And see error log:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: modelo.DAO.HIBERNATE.POJO.Curso cannot be cast to POJO.Curso
```

Comment: Well, the message speaks for itself: you're querying instances of the entity modelo.DAO.HIBERNATE.POJO.Curso, so you get a list containing instances of modelo.DAO.HIBERNATE.POJO.Curso, and you're trying to cast those objects to POJO.Curso.

Comment: List<Curso> refers to a list of POJO.Curso and your query is returning a list of modelo.DAO.HIBERNATE.POJO.Curso. Correct your imports.